# Google Cloud Platform tutorial Issue - Detecting anomalies in financial transactions by using AI Platform, Dataflow, and BigQuery

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-dataflow, google-cloud-pubsub

I tried following the google cloud platform tutorial "[Detecting anomalies in financial transactions by using AI Platform, Dataflow, and BigQuery](https://cloud.google.com/architecture/detecting-anomalies-in-financial-transactions)".
I was able to complete most of the steps but was unable to execute the dataflow job using the command in the tutorial. This is the [link](https://cloud.google.com/architecture/detecting-anomalies-in-financial-transactions#run-pipeline) to the step.

[image: Run the Dataflow pipeline]

I replaced the "myProject" and was able to submit a job, but it keeps on failing. I get error message as follows.

[image]

Comment: Maybe your answer is here: https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/df-ml-anomaly-detection. Check if the gcr.io image exists or if you have to use this: --image=gcr.io/${PROJECT_ID}/df-ml-anomaly-detection:latest. Also, can you please post the Dataflow image of the processes please ?

Comment: Hi R.Maharjan, is your issue resolved?

Comment: Correct, https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/df-ml-anomaly-detection has the source code to rebuild the missing image.

Comment: @BrunoVolpato Yes i have the source code. But do you have any additional info to rebuild the image?

Comment: @SakshiGatyan Not yet.

Comment: Hi @R.Maharjan, did rebuilding the image resolved your issue?